# Why and is typecasting in the example important?

Tags: android

It seems to run fine, but i just wonder why it shows an error when I try to implement the typecasting.

Eg. when the ratingBar is typecast as a (RatingBar) and when the editText is typecast as a (EditText).

Any advice? pointers?

```
package com.example.benmohammad.contacts;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;

class StudentFormViewHelper {


 private final Activity activity;

 public StudentFormViewHelper(Activity activity) {

  this.activity = activity;
 }

 private String getName() {

  return getTextFieldValue(R.id.student_form_name);


 }
 private String getTextFieldValue(int fieldId) {

  EditText field = activity.findViewById(fieldId);
  String value = field.getText().toString();
  return value;
 }
 private String getAddress() {
  return getTextFieldValue(R.id.student_form_address);
 }
 private String getPhoneNumber() {
  return getTextFieldValue(R.id.student_form_phonenumber);

 }
 private String getWebsite() {
  return getTextFieldValue(R.id.student_form_website);
 }
 private String getEmail() {
  return getTextFieldValue(R.id.student_form_email);

 }

 public Student createAStudent() {
  return new Student(getName(), getAddress(), getPhoneNumber(), getWebsite(), getEmail(), getGrading());
 }

 private double getGrading() {
  RatingBar rating = activity.findViewById(R.id.student_form_grading);
  return rating.getRating();
 }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What are you trying and where?

Comment: It runs without typecasting which is what i don't understand 
eg. private double getGrading() {
        RatingBar rating = activity.findViewById(R.id.student_form_grading);

see that i havent typecasted before the activity.findViewId but if i do ...
private double getGrading() {

RatingBar rating = (RatingBar)activity.findViewById...... this chucks a syntax error underneath the typecast "(RatingBar)"...

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typecasting your UI components declared in your XML is in important because if you are accessing those components you use `findViewById()` which returns a `View`. So say you are working with an `EditText`, if you don't cast the returned view of `activity.findViewById("my_edit_text")` to `EditText` then you will be working with a `View` and there may be certain actions or methods that you will not be able to take or call. It seems unlikely that you would be able to set your `EditText` to a `View` in the first place with seeing some error.